# Always return 404 error

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404

I'm new to magento.

The problem is just like this:

Everytime I navigate to `"About us"` or `footer-links` in `front-end-site` from choosing category product, It always return 404, page not found. But when I refresh the page and go directly to `"about us"`, it wont happen.

Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Web Server Rewrites is on or off? and also check if mod_rewrite is enabled or not?

Comment: Do you have a link to the site in question? The information in your question isn't really sufficient - it could be problems with the design not generating the links correctly, rewrite rules, configuration issues - many things really...

Comment: The site is not online yet. Maybe I could post some screenshot. When I choosed a product then clicked "about us", I will get a 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

First Clear you magento cache from **Dashboard -> System -> Cache Management** 
Select All then click Flush Magento Cache and Flush Magento Storage

And do this to

**Dashboard -> System -> Index Management** 
Select ALL then click submit and make sure you set action Reindex Data

Comment: It happens in the front-end. If I choosed a product then click to "about us" then I will get a 404 page